# vscode/eslint complaining Parsing error: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have the following `index.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'mytypes' {
  interface Constructor<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
  }

  //etc.
```

VSCode highlights the interface keyword:

[image]

```
Parsing error: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module

  1 | declare module 'someproject' {
> 2 |   interface Constructor<T> {
    |   ^
  3 |     new (...args: any[]): T;
  4 |   }
  5 |eslint
```

Looks like an eslint error but I cannot tell which from the error message

Answer (score 39):

You can add .eslintignore

```
/**/*.d.ts
```

The eslint rule mistakenly treats d.ts as js