# ESLint: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I tried adding this to my **interfaces.ts** file but ESLint isn't having it:

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    // extends React's HTMLAttributes
    name?: string;
    ref?: HTMLAnchorElement;
    cssClass?: string;
  }
}
```

**ESLint Parsing error:** `Only declares and type imports are allowed

I get this same error with this piece of code that lives in **images.d.ts** where it's not liking the `const` keyword:

```
declare module '*.png' {
 const value: any;
 export = value;
}
```

Does everyone just put this kind of code to custom `.d.ts` files and tell eslint to ignore it?

inside declare module`
**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors"
  ],
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {"ecmaFeatures": {"jsx": true}},
    "env": {"mocha": true},
    "rules": {"comma-dangle": 0,
    "max-classes-per-file": [0],
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": [0],
    "complexity": ["error", {"max": 6}],
    "handle-callback-err": "error",
    "import/default": [0],
    "import/order": [0],
    "max-statements": ["error", 30],
    "no-console": [0],
    "no-constant-condition": "error",
    "no-param-reassign": ["error", {"props": false}],
    "no-process-exit": "error",
    "no-useless-call": "error",
    "react/no-danger": [0],
    "react/jsx-indent-props": [0],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, {"extensions": [".tsx"]}],
    "react/jsx-indent": [0],
    "react/jsx-tag-spacing": ["error", { "beforeSelfClosing": "always" }],
    "react/jsx-sort-props": ["error", {"ignoreCase": false, "noSortAlphabetically": false}],
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": [0, { "ignorePureComponents": true }],
    "react/no-multi-comp": [0, { "ignoreStateless": true }],
    "react/require-optimization": [0],
    "react/prop-types": [0],
    "react/no-array-index-key": [1],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [0],
    "react/destructuring-assignment": [0],
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": [1, "after-props"],
    "jsx-one-expression-per-line": [0],
    "import/extensions": [0],
    "import/no-unresolved": [0],
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [0],
    "one-var": [0],
    "max-len": ["error", { "code": 140 }],
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": [0],
    "no-shadow": [0],
    "function-paren-newline": [0],
    "no-tabs": [0],
    "indent": [1, "tab"],
    "no-use-before-define": [0],
    "no-nested-ternary": [1],
    "no-restricted-syntax": [1],
    "no-plusplus": [1],
    "react/no-find-dom-node": [1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode/eslint complaining Parsing error: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989643/vscode-eslint-complaining-parsing-error-only-declares-and-type-imports-are-allo)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways you can solve this

1. ESLint thinks of `.d.ts` files as `.js`

   Add them to your `.eslintignore` file which will fix the issue for you :)

   ```
   /**/*.d.ts
   ```
2. Add this package `yarn add --dev @typescript-eslint/parser`

   Reference: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/issues/191#issuecomment-561380265)

   And add to your .eslintrc

   ```
   module.exports = {
       ...
       parserOptions: {
       parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
   },
   ```